# How to update the connection string for an asp.net entity project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I have received a sample code for an asp.net web forms application using Northwind database. The first conn string gave, "The underlying provider failed on Open." error. So, I have changed it to the second one pointing to a locally running sql server. But now I am getting this error: Some required information is missing from the connection string. The 'metadata' keyword is always required.

```
<add name="Northwind" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Northwind.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Northwind.ssdl|    res://*/App_Code.Northwind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|    DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>


<add name="Northwind" connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=my server;Initial     Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Before you go too far, are you aware you are working with pretty old technology? If this project is for a learning experience you should fast-forward a decade or so. Otherwise, you need to add a lot more detail to get a good answer.

Comment: Essentially I want to know how to update an entity framework connection string from pointing to an mdf file to a locally running sql server

Answer (score 0):

Now this connectionstring work without error

```
</connectionStrings>
<add name="Northwind" connectionString="Data Source=my server;Initial 
Catalog=Northwind;ID=sa;Password=mypassword;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

Answer (score 0):

your provider name is incorrect:

```
System.Data.EntityClient // incorrect
System.Data.SqlClient    // correct
```

remove first connection string and put following connectin string to web.config file:

```
<add name="Northwind" connectionString="Server=.;Initial Catalog=ProjectDb;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

also set `connectionStringName` in your DbContext constructor

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
  public ApplicationDbContext() : base("name=Northwind")
  {

  }

}
```

Comment: when I use "server", I get "server not allowed" error

Comment: @Massey do you install sql server?

Comment: @Massey  this is you sever name, I don't now that what is your server names. if you install sql server default server is `.` i update my answer.